# Set single checkbox in a recyclerview

Tags: android

I forgot how to check a single checkbox in a recyclerview.  I looked at [how to have single choice on checkbox in recyclerview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64221556/how-to-have-single-choice-on-checkbox-in-recyclerview) but you shouldn't need to call notifyDataSetChanged.  I tried this and the wrong checkbox is being selected:

```
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.CheckBox
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.tps.challenge.R
import com.tps.challenge.domain.Store
import com.tps.challenge.ui.Event

class StoreFeedAdapter(
    private val stores: List<Store>,
    private val itemClickListener: (Event<Store>) -> Unit
): RecyclerView.Adapter<StoreItemViewHolder>() {

    private var prevSelectedPos: Int = 0
    private var currSelectedPos: Int = 0

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): StoreItemViewHolder {
        return StoreItemViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_store, parent, false)
        ).also { viewHolder ->
            viewHolder.storeImage.setOnClickListener {
                val selectedStore = stores[viewHolder.adapterPosition]
                itemClickListener.invoke(
                    Event(selectedStore)
                )
            }
            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnClickListener {
                currSelectedPos = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                notifyItemChanged(prevSelectedPos)
                notifyItemChanged(currSelectedPos)
                prevSelectedPos = currSelectedPos
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: StoreItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.checkbox.isSelected = currSelectedPos == position
        val store = stores[position]

        with(holder.itemView) {
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name).text = store.name
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.description).text = store.desc
            Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
                .load(store.coverImgUrl)
                .into(holder.storeImage)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return stores.size
    }
}

class StoreItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val storeImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_store)
    val checkbox: CheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_select)
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with Kotlin but just a guess. Assume that Int is an object and not a primitive value and notifyItemChanged run asynchronous.

Comment: So let say `previous=0` and `current=1`, you expect `notifyItemChanged(previous=0)` will run first and then `notifyItemChanged(current=1)` second, and at last replace `previous=1`.

Comment: But the actual case might be 1st run of `notifyItemChanged(previous=0)` is not true while running. It will suddenly become `notifyItemChanged(previous=1)` during the process.

Comment: No it is running synchronously, you can check by logging position.  If position 1 is clicked, then position 2, onBindViewHolder prints the position is 1 and then 2.

Comment: You are right. Just one thing I have found, shouldn't you call `holder.checkBox.setChecked(false)` instead of just change the property of isSelected?

Comment: If you don't want to invoke `notifyDatasetChanged` manually, use `ListAdapter(DIFF_CALLBACK)` instead of `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class StoreFeedAdapter(
    private val stores: List<Store>,
    private val itemClickListener: (Event<Store>) -> Unit
      ): RecyclerView.Adapter<StoreItemViewHolder>() {

    private var prevSelectedPos: Int = 0
    private var currSelectedPos: Int = -1

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): StoreItemViewHolder {
        return StoreItemViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_store, parent, false)
        ).also { viewHolder ->
            viewHolder.storeImage.setOnClickListener {
                val selectedStore = stores[viewHolder.adapterPosition]
                itemClickListener.invoke(
                    Event(selectedStore)
                )
            }
            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnClickListener {
                currSelectedPos = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                 notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: StoreItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
       
          if(currSelectedPos == position){checked}else{unChecked}
        val store = stores[position]

        with(holder.itemView) {
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name).text = store.name
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.description).text = store.desc
            Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
               .load(store.coverImgUrl)
                .into(holder.storeImage)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return stores.size
    }
}

class StoreItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val storeImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_store)
    val checkbox: CheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_select)
}
```